# Will the water in the pipe attached to the bottom of the water tank slow down or speed up when it is emptying?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, flow, bernoulli-equation

Outside the pipe there is atmospheric pressure as above the surface of the water in the container.

What will the differential equations look like - fluid velocity in the pipe and x(t)? The water in the pipe, until it is emptied, is subjected to a constantly decreasing but non-zero force, and at the same time the mass of water in the pipe is constantly increasing. For simplicity, A1>>>A2, so the velocity of the fluid in water tank compared to the fluid in the pipe is negligible

I guess the equations can somehow be derived from energy transfer, i.e. d Ep/dt = - d Ek/dt, but in the kinetic energy term we have to take into account the time dependence of mass m(t).

We assume there is no friction in pipe. We can assume also that at the beginning all the energy is accumulated in the potential energy in the water tank

P.S. 1 Can we talk about steady flow at all in the "long" time interval? After all, velocity depends on the height of the water in the tank, which changes over time

P.S. 2 How to look at this system?
On the one hand, my intuition tells me that energy is constant at any point in the fluid flow, but on the other hand, it will look as if one part of the system (tank) transfers energy to another part (pipe). Analogous to the oscillating fluid in a tank-pipe-tank system

[image]

Comment: "and at the same time the mass of water in the pipe is constantly increasing." So the pipe is very long and keeps filling? Or does water eventually get to the end of the pipe and escape?

Comment: the pipe is long enough that all the water from the tank will fit in it, but it will not reach its end (which is open - atmospheric pressure)

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to obtain the DE relating the height, $y$ of water in the tank (initial height, $y_0$) to the time $t$ from release into the pipe, if we assume that the flow in the pipe is slow enough to be laminar, and for acquisition rate of KE to be negligible compared with work done per second against resistive (viscous)  forces.

In that case we can use Poiseuille's formula for $\Phi$, the volumetric rate of flow of water through the pipe, in terms of the pressure difference, $\rho gy$, between the ends of the water-length, $x$ in the pipe.

As water volume is conserved, for a pipe of inner radius $r$ fed from a tank of inner cross-sectional area $A_1$, we have
$$\pi r^2 (x-x_0)=A_1(y_0-y)$$
Here, $x_0$ is the length of water in the pipe at time $t=0$.

Also,
$$\Phi=\pi r^2\frac{dx}{dt}=\ –A_1\frac{dy}{dt}.$$
You should now be able to set up the DE. I find
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\ -\frac{\pi r^4 \rho g y}{8A\eta x}\ \ \ \ \ \text{in which}\ \ \ \ \ x=\frac{A(y_0-y)}{\pi r^2}+x_0$$

I can't solve this DE analytically. However it's easy to give a qualitative answer to the question posed in your title: the flow rate will decrease because the pressure gradient across the length of water in the tube will decrease. It does so for two reasons: the pressure difference, $y\rho g$ between its ends decreases, and the length, $x$, itself increases!

Why don't we put $x_0=0$? In other words, why don't we assume that there is no water in the tube at $t=0$? In that case, according to our equation, $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ would be infinite at $t=0$. Poiseuille's equation wouldn't be applicable at $t=0$ and just after as the infinite flow-rate that it predicts is unphysical.

On the other hand, putting $x_0=0$ would make our equation much neater, namely:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\ -\frac{v_1 y}{y_0-y}\ \ \ \ \ \text{in which}\ \ \ \ \ v_1=\frac{\pi^2 r^6 \rho g)}{8A^2 \eta}$$
This equation won't hold immediately after the water has been released into the tube.

Comment: But what about other questions? And what about this - we have a certain amount of energy at the beginning, if the flow rate becomes 0 over time, the final energy will also be 0. So where does it go if there is no loss? And again - if we have a tank-pipe (even very long)-tank system, the energy does not "disappear" but accumulates in tank2 and then backwards - oscillation

Comment: (a) "But what about other questions?" Perhaps someone will answer them. (b) "So where does it go if there is no loss?" But there IS energy loss, i.e. energy dissipation: as the cylindrical shells of water in the pipe slide over each other, energy is transferred to random thermal energy of the water molecules, i.e. the grav'l energy of water in the tank finishes up as internal thermal energy of water in the pipe: the water gets a little hotter. (c) In the tank-to-tank system, with not too thin or long a pipe, you would have damped oscillations. The energy would still finish up as thermal.

Comment: Can we somehow use bernouli equation or "energy approach" to derive these equations? What would change if the water tank was "thin", i.e. the surface area would be equal to the pipe - the system would be basically an "L" shaped pipe?

Comment: The equations towards the end of my answer are based on Poiseuille's equation, which assumes laminar flow in the pipe with viscous (energy dissipating) forces operating. I don't see how an 'energy approach' which assumes viscous forces but doesn't use Poiseuille could yield a flow rate. Bernouilli's theorem assumes negligible viscosity and no energy dissipation. I don't think this is realistic for liquid flowing through a long pipe. Incidentally, the last of my equations for $dy/dx$ can be integrated, but the results are messy. I suspect that I haven't helped you much. Sorry.